# Python program with variables

Tags: python, variables

How to use a cell  to compute the value of the polynomial  = ^3 + ^2 +  +   at  =2  using  =3 ,  =1 ,  =−3 , and  =−5 . Then print the value of the variable   ?

## Assign the constants a-d

```
a = 3
b = 1
c = -3
d = -5
```

Comment: Please change your title..

Comment: What is a "cell"?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please edit your question: a) supply code for your problem, b) describe what you have tried so far. Help people to help you

Answer (score 0):

at first you need to declare the initial variable as

```
x=2
a=3
b=1
c=-3
d=-5
```

and then you can use your variable in your formula as below

```
y=((a*(x**3))+(b*(x**2))+(c*x)+d)
```

and then you can print "y" value with

```
print(y)
```